# Stop AJAX setTimeout, if texbox value length is greater than 2 or user starts to write something inside that

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

html code:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input id="kerd" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="" type="text">
<button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit">send</button>
<button name="submit" type="submit" style="float: left" class="btn btn-success submit">i saw</button>
</form>
```

script:

```
<script>
get_fb();
function get_fb(){
var feedback = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "task.php",
    async: false
}).success(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){get_fb();}, 10000);
}).responseText;
$('div.section').html(feedback);
   if ($(".section").html().length > 0) {
 $('.section').show();
} 
}
 function get_f(){
            if($("#kerd").val().length>2){
                clearTimeout(t);
            } 
}
</script>
```

this code is updating my page from my database every 10 seconds, i want to stop this ajax code if user start to write somethings inside my textbox input but, these codes are not working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**:

html:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input id="kerd" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="" type="text">
<button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit">send</button>
<button name="submit" type="submit" style="float: left" class="btn btn-success submit">i saw</button>
```

script:

```
<script>
get_fb();
var t;
function get_fb(){
var feedback = $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "task.php",
async: false
}).success(function(){
    t = setTimeout(function(){get_fb();}, 10000);
}).responseText;
$('div.section').html(feedback);
if ($(".section").html().length > 0) {
$('.section').show();
} 
}
function get_f(){
        if($("#kerd").val().length>2){
            clearTimeout(t);
        } 
}
</script>
function stop(){
                clearTimeout(t);
}
```